# data race reported from two distinct mutexes

Tags: go

An interesting issue has arisen today where I have code that contains more than one Mutex, each covering locking for distinct Maps.

Here is a **similar in struct** of my source code that I am using:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    dogMutex sync.RWMutex
    dogMap   map[int]Dog // keyed by PID
    catMutex sync.RWMutex
    catMap   map[int]Cat // keyed by (localAddress + localPort)
}
```

A more detailed example of the issue is here:
https://play.golang.org/p/eic8q2VrNq

After building the executable with 'go build -race ..." the generated executable reports the following race

As the code is way more complex than the example above, it is interesting to notice that the data race is reported on the areas indicated in the code.

The following stack is from the real application.

1) The **write** operation reported on wwww.go:95 is equivalent to my WRITE comment in the code (MethodOne)

2) The **previous read** operattion reported on wwww.go:218 is equivalent to my READ comment in the code (MethodTwo)

```
=================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c420017890 by goroutine 97:
  runtime.mapassign1()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:442 +0x0
  main.(*NetworkManager).MethodOne()
      /opt/doppler/src/xxx/yyy/wwww.go:95 +0x745

Previous read at 0x00c420017890 by goroutine 70:
  runtime.mapiterinit()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:620 +0x0
  main.NetworkManager.MethodTwo()
      /opt/xxx/src/xxx/yyy/wwww.go:218 +0x1e9
  main.(*NetworkManager).SomethingELse()
      /opt/xxx/src/xxx/yyy/wwww.go:174 +0x99d
  main.(*NetworkManager).SomethingFurther()
      /opt/xxx/src/xxx/yyy/wwww.go:102 +0x3c
```

I am wondering if this is a proper way of using mutexes. My code has much concurrency, but I am focusing this question on the fact that the race detector is reporting based on Apples vs Bananas (two completely distinct mutexes)

Comment: using go version go1.7 linux/amd64

Comment: I have a feeling you've removed the race in your simplified example. Can you make something that replicates the race, or provide the actual methods and types from your code?

Comment: The code is quite inter-dependent. It would not help. But to be honest, there is actually no race really, except that it is being reported. This is why I am puzzled.

Comment: I agree with @JimB using your example code and setting -race flag I can not reproduce any race report.

Comment: The race detector is pretty much guaranteed to not have false positives. There must be some relation between the data structures triggering the race.

Comment: Well, good at least that it appears this is "okay". I was afraid there would be some thing wrong with my struct and approach, but this seems valid. I will try to do more isolation. thanks for your comments. I will detail further as I dig deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to take a guess, but one common cause of this issue is accidentally passing the struct which contains the pointers by value instead of by reference. For example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    dogMutex sync.RWMutex
    dogMap   map[int]Dog // keyed by PID
    catMutex sync.RWMutex
    catMap   map[int]Cat // keyed by (localAddress + localPort)
}

func (s MyStruct) Example() {
    // this lock doesn't actually work, but the map access does because its a 
    // reference type
    s.catMutex.Lock()
    s.catMap[1] = Cat{}
    s.catMutex.Unlock()
}
```

Another possibility is that perhaps you are passing the maps into your init:

```
func (s *MyStruct) Init(cats map[int]Cat) {
    s.catMap = cats
}
```

And then you are modifying the map somewhere outside of the struct. If that's the case you need to create a new map and copy all the values.

Incidentally `go vet` can detect many of these issues, try running it on your code: https://golang.org/cmd/vet/. (Also worth a try is the [metalinter](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter))

Comment: perfectly what my issue was (methods were by value vs reference). Great suggestions. I wasnt aware of the vet tool or metaliner